# Android Webview finish loading before load another web

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am currently working on a testing app which is used to test the speeds of a list of websites. The app is supposed to automatically visit all these websites one by one, and I use the approach as:

```
    mainWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){                   
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            endtime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "The Time:" + ((endtime - starttime)/1000) +"."+ (((endtime - starttime)/100)%10), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            resultList.add(url + " : "+ ((endtime - starttime)/1000) +"."+ (((endtime - starttime)/100)%10));
            timer.cancel();

            if (index < testWebsiteList.length - 1){
                Log.i("TEST" , "//INDEX: " + index);
                index ++;
                mainWebview.loadUrl(testWebsiteList[index]);
            }

            mainWebview.clearCache(true);
        }
```

However, the problem is that the once the webview started loading the first web, it will give such a logcat output:

```
//INDEX: 0
//INDEX: 1
//INDEX: 2
//INDEX: 3
//INDEX: 4
//INDEX: 5
//INDEX: 6
//INDEX: 7 ...
```

And only the last web is correctly loaded out, all the web within 0-last is not shown but the onPageFinsihed method is fired.

How can i solve the problem to make that I can visit the websites one by one before the last one finished.

Answer (score -1):

Page is done loaded at onPageFinished. But it can t render immediately that. So you couldn t catch to finish loading. You can apply picturelistener listener to your webview. This can catch webview render when finish. Apply this code :

```
webview.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

                public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
                    if (picture != null) {
                                                //Your progress in here
                                            }
                                    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for you reply first, but how to know that the last picture is loaded?